# i want to display this records in form of gridview as well count total records how should i do..?

Tags: gridview

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pDashboard]

```
AS
```

BEGIN

```
DECLARE @TotalUSers INT
DECLARE @PendingQuery INT
DECLARE @RepliedQuery INT


SELECT  @TotalUSers = COUNT(*)
FROM    register


SELECT  @PendingQuery = COUNT(*)
FROM    USerQuery
WHERE   QueryReply is null

SELECT  @RepliedQuery = COUNT(*)
FROM    UserQuery
WHERE   QueryReply is not null


SELECT  @TotalUSers as TOTALUSERS,
        @PendingQuery as PENDINGQUERY,
        @RepliedQuery as RepliedQuery;
```

END

i want to display this records in form of gridview as well count total records how should i do in asp.net?

Comment: and if suppose i want to display all user detail instead of count so what should i do should i remove count..?

Answer (score 0):

To display serial number in data grid you have need to use indexof each row for example.

```
Container.ItemIndex+1
```